# Is $X=\left\{(W(t),W(at)); t \ge 0\right\}$ a Lévy process, for $a \in \left(0,1\right)$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, levy-processes

This question is making me crazy for a long time:

Is $\boldsymbol{X}=\left\{(W(t),W(at)); t \ge 0\right\}$ a Lévy process where $W(t)$ is a standard Brownian motion and $a \in \left(0,1\right)$?

My answer is no, since increments are not independent. Indeed if I compute the covariance matrix $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ for $s<t$ I get:

\begin{equation*}
   \boldsymbol{\Sigma} = cov\left(\boldsymbol{X}(t)-\boldsymbol{X}(s),\boldsymbol{X}(s)\right)
\end{equation*}

I obtain that:

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\Sigma} = \begin{bmatrix}
(W(t)-W(s))W(s) & (W(t)-W(s))W(as) \\
(W(at)-W(as))W(s) & (W(at)-W(as))W(as) 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

If I look at the term $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{2,1}$ I have that:

\begin{equation*}
\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{2,1} = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            at-as & \quad at <s \\
            s-as & \quad at>s
        \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation*}
Since $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{1,2}$ is not zero, the increments are not independent and hence $\boldsymbol{X}$ is not a Lévy proess.

Nevertheless, if I compute the characteristic function at $t$ of $\boldsymbol{X}$ I have:

\begin{equation*}
\phi_{X(t)}(u_{1},u_{2}) = e^{-\frac{1}{2} t [u_{1},u_{2}] \begin{bmatrix}
1 & a \\
a & a
\end{bmatrix} [u_{1},u_{2}]^{T}}
\end{equation*}
which is the characteristic function of an infinitely divisible law, by the Lévy-Kinchin theorem. Hence the process must be Lévy. And this is in contrast to what we proved above.

Probably I'm missing something but I can't figure out what is wrong in my reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I don't think Levy-Khintchine theorem says what you think it does. Namely, it does not say that "given the characteristic function of the process at time t, if it is infinitely divisible, then the process is Levy". I think it says that "there exists a Levy process whose law matches the law at time t", in which case, it is easy to see what the process should be, since you gave its covariance. Namely, let $W_1(t), W_2(t)$ be iid BMs. Then, $X(t) \stackrel{d}{=} (\sqrt{1-a} W_1(t) + \sqrt{a} W_2(t), \sqrt{a} W_2(t)) $ for each fixed $t$, and this should be a Levy process.

Comment: thank you so much. I have another doubt. Suppose that a $Y$ process is Lévy and the other $X$ one is not. Assume that they have the same characteristic function $\phi_{X(t)}(u) = \phi_{Y(t)}(u)$ for all $t>0$. Then $X(t)\stackrel{d}{=}Y(t)$. Hence the law of $X$ at time $t$ is infinitely divisible. This ONLY means that there exist a Lévy process (i.e. $Y$), but I'm allowed to construct another process (i.e. $X$) such that its law at $t$ is infinitely divible without the process $X$ being a Lévy process. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I am not super confident though.

Comment: I've checked all the details and you are perfectly right. We can refer to the Theorem 7.10 of the book of Sato - Lévy Processes and Infinitely Divisible distributions. If a law is infinitely divisible then there exists a Lévy process associated to it. But the converse is not true in general.